# Efficiently batch collected events from SharedFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

All I have is a `SharedFlow`. Collecting and handling each event is expensive, but consuming and handling 100 events is only slightly more expensive than handling a single event, so I need to batch or buffer results of the SharedFlow to handle multiple at once.

The `SharedFlow` emits intermittently, but at an extremely high rate when it does, faster than the `handle` function can process. Due to constrained resources (low memory and already constrained processor), I can't simply launch from another `CoroutineScope` to handle single events. If I process each event individually, memory will fill up too fast.

I have to consume the events as quickly and efficiently as possible without loss.

```
val injectedSharedFlow: SharedFlow<MyData>

// My inefficient handling
aCoroutineScope.launch {
    
    injectedSharedFlow.collect { aSingleMyData ->
        handleSingleMyData(aSingleMyData)
    }
    
}

// What I want to do
aCoroutineScope.launch {

    // Collect up to 100 items while there are items in flow
    injectedSharedFlow.collectMany { multipleDataList ->
        handleMultipleMyData(multipleDataList)
    }

}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a different way to build this operator. Might be worth benchmarking them both to compare.

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.chunked(size: Int): Flow<List<T>> = flow {
    var list = ArrayList(size)
    collect {
        list += it
        if (list.size == size) {
            emit(list)
            list = ArrayList(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the entire problem. This works as long as long as the number of items in the flow (n) are `n % size == 0`, but holds the remainder until `size` elements are in the Flow. I guess I can have a loop on a short delay that gets reset with each collected item and then handles what remains in `list` as the delay timeout occurs, but I'd like to avoid a `delay` in my situation if I can. Given events are emitted intermittently, the current solution would hold the remaining values for some time.

Comment: How could it possibly know when it should emit without a delay? The only way is if the items in your source flow also include information about how long it will be until the next emission, and you could use that to determine whether to wait for the next item. Or if the last item in each burst had a boolean in it to tell you to go ahead.